# How to get this layout with 2 column?

Tags: css, html

I need to do something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97zZM.jpg

with the first black column always displayed on the left side of the page.

I have write this code but it doesn't work:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>


<body>
<div id="allcontent">


<div id="sidebar"> </div>

<div id="center">

<p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p> <p> TEST </p>

</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#allcontent{ width:1000px; margin:auto; }

#center{ 
border-right:solid 1px #d0d9e8; height:80%; width:760px;
padding: 35px 10px 10px 0px;
float:right;
}

#sidebar { 
width:200px; height: 100%; float:left;  
background:#000;
border:solid 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set margins to 0 for both and padding to 0 for sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you should used `display table properties`  as like this

**Css**

```
  #allcontent{ width:1000px; margin:auto;
display:table;}

#center{ 
border-right:solid 1px #d0d9e8;  width:760px;
padding: 35px 10px 10px 30px;
display:table-cell;
}

#sidebar { 
width:200px;
    display:table-cell;  
background:#000;
border:solid 1px black;
}​
```

live Demo http://jsfiddle.net/99Ych/

Answer (score -1):

In your css you have 100% height in your black column(it dosen't have a parent to inherit it's height), in order to make 100% height work wrap your column inside a div with a defined height, you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3YW2C/ that by defining a height, floats are actually working